# Count the number of singletons in a text file using Golang

Tags: string, count, go, singleton

How can I count the number of strings that occurs exactly once in a text file using GO?
I have read some of the package description of golang, maybe I should use bufio.NewScanner to read the contents of the passed-in file a line at a time. Then I try to use map to count the occurrence of each string:

stringcount := make(map[string]int)

how can I update the data of this empty map? For example, if the first string is "hello" in the file, how to make stringcount["hello"] = 1?

Here is my try:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    frequencyofWord := map[string]int{}

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }

    s := strings.Fields(scanner.Text()) //one more question : is strings.Fields used correctly here?
    countSingleton(s)

}

func countSingleton(a []string) {
    //here how to update the map according to the text read ?//
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to reflect the actual question you're asking.  Are you asking what the difference between Scanner and Reader is?  Are you asking how to find the unique strings in a list?  Are you asking how to read the lines from a file?  Don't ask all three at once.  I suspect each of these are already answered elsewhere, but some clarity will help us point you where you need to go.

Comment: thanks for the reply,I will try to make it clear. The main question is how to find the unique string in a text file and output how many unique strings are there in this file.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about maps.  Have you gone through the tutorial? http://tour.golang.org/

Comment: @KyleLemons Yes I did, but the tour only gives example that assigns fixed values to a map. I wonder how to do it when takes a file as input. I update my question again, giving what I have tried to do.

Comment: @user3221327 Are you sure you mean _string_? Because checking each substring of a text file against each other substring is pretty damn expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`bufio.NewScanner`](http://godoc.org/bufio#NewScanner) to break apart the lines, use [`strings.Fields`](http://godoc.org/strings#Fields) to get the words, and use [`yourMap[theWord]++`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#IncDec_statements) to count the words.

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/3H6gfBlQL5

To get the list of the unique words, [iterate](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) over the map keys and [append](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) them to a [slice](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), and then [sort](http://godoc.org/sort#Strings) them.